# No result defined for action and result input after adding struts2 JQuery Datepicker

Tags: java, forms, struts2, datepicker, struts2-jquery

I have a struts2 form in which I added a Datepicker as a field. But after adding the DatePicker, when I submit my form, the Tomcat error msg shows..

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.abc.RecBackupConfigurationAction and result input
```

If I remove datepicker from my form, then everything runs fine. I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

My JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<sj:head />
<script>
    function grabDispositions(campaign) {
        $.post("getCampDispositionsRecBackupConf", {campname: campaign}, function(response) {
            $('#disposition_td').html(response);
        });
    }
</script>
<h3>Recording Backup Configuration</h3>
<div id="backup_conf">
    <s:form theme="simple" action="saveDetailsRecBackupConf" method="post" name="viewConfiguration">
        <!--Rule Name : <input name="rulename" id="rulename">-->
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Rule Name : </td>
                <td><input name="rulename" id="rulename"></td>
                <td>Frequency : </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="frequency" name="frequency">
                        <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
                        <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
                        <option value="60">60 minutes</option>
                        <option value="120">120 minutes</option>
                        <option value="240">240 minutes</option>
                        <option value="480">480 minutes</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Backup Server: </td>
                <td><input name="backupserver"></td>
                <td>Backup Directory: </td>
                <td><input name="backupdir"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select Campaign :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:select id="campaign" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Campaign" list="campaignList"  name="campname" theme="simple" onchange="grabDispositions(this.value)"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Select Dispositions :
                </td>
                <td id='disposition_td'>
                    <s:select id="dispositions" list="dispositionList"  name="dispositions" multiple="true" theme="simple"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status : </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="status">
                        <option value="active">Active</option>
                        <option value="inactive">InActive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>Select Date : </td>
                <td>
                    <sj:datepicker size="14" theme="simple" id="addedon" name="addedon" label="Select a Date/Time" timepicker="true" timepickerFormat="HH:mm:ss" displayFormat="yy-mm-dd" readonly="true"></sj:datepicker>            
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="SUBMIT" id="save" />
    </s:form>
</div>
```

My struts-file mapping:

```
<action name="*RecBackupConf" method="{1}" class="com.abc.RecBackupConfigurationAction">
        <result name="addConfigurationDetails" type="tiles">recBackupConfiguration</result>
        <result name="saveDetails" type="tiles">viewRecordingConfiguration</result>
        <result name="getCampDispositions">contaque/recBackup/dispositions.jsp</result>
        <result name="displayDetails" >contaque/recBackup/editConfiguration.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

How should I add the Datepicker to my form???

Comment: You have already added Datepicker, not you have to add `INPUT` result.

Comment: And then you will see actual error.

Comment: I've try this with `input` result and it works fine but Action class method not called.

Comment: Of course. Because an exception is being thrown, look in the log.

Comment: What is the property type receiving the date? What's in the logs?